# Using Running Total In

Tags: excel, charts, pivot, pivot-table

I need to plot the data considering all Row-Values

I've used Running Total In but it seems there's a break when the "Year" changes.

I'd like to continuously accumulate the values, even the "Year" changes. For example, in Q1 - 2019 I'd like to show the value 2.109.822 (1.972.961 + 136.861), and so on...

[image: Pivot Table Print Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PivotField Calculation `xlRunningTotal` shows the running total for successive items in the Base field. Therefore at the change of the `Year` the running total breaks. (see [XlPivotFieldCalculation enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpivotfieldcalculation))

The suggested workaround would be to physically create a combined field at the `DataSource` that concatenates the `Year` and the `Quarter` Fields and to have this combined field as the only row field in the PivotTable.

[image]